# React w/hooks: prevent re-rendering component with a function as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have:

```
const AddItemButton = React.memo(({ onClick }) => {
  // Goal is to make sure this gets printed only once
  console.error('Button Rendered!');
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Add Item</button>;
});

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems(items.concat(Math.random()));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <AddItemButton onClick={addItem} />
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any time I add an item, the `<AddItemButton />` gets re-rendered because addItem is a new instance. I tried memoizing addItem:

```
 const addItemMemoized = React.memo(() => addItem, [setItems])
```

But this is reusing the setItems from the first render, while

```
 const addItemMemoized = React.memo(() => addItem, [items])
```

Doesn't memoize since `items` reference changes.

I can'd do

```
 const addItem = () => {
   items.push(Math.random());
   setItems(items);
 }
```

Since that doesn't change the reference of `items` and nothing gets updated.

One weird way to do it is:

```
  const [, frobState] = useState();
  const addItemMemoized = useMemo(() => () => {
    items.push(Math.random());
    frobState(Symbol())
  }, [items]);
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way that doesn't require extra state references.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The current preferred route is [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), which is the same as your `useMemo` solution, but with additional possible optimizations in the future. Pass an empty array `[]` to make sure the function will *always* have the same reference for the lifetime of the component.

Here, you also want to use the [functional state update form](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), to make sure the item is always being added based on the current state.

```
  const addItem = useCallback(() => {
    setItems(items => [...items, Math.random()]);
  }, []);
```

Comment: "useCallback(fn, inputs) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, inputs)." which is what I did. But because items reference changes due to spread/concat, it doesn't get memoized

Comment: Well, here, you can change `[items]` to `[]` and it'll still work, since the update depends on previous state. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I think the key here is to use a function in setItems! Thanks @kingdaro

Comment: Yep, that'll do it :P Sure thing